# Creating a Function with multiple operations in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently doing a project with baby name data. I am looking at the most popular male and female baby names in each decade starting with the 1950s. I am trying to create a function that will print out the top name for the data set that I input.

So far I have successfully created two datasets for each decade (one male and the other female)

This is the code that I have for the function but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work...

```
def getTopName(data):
    (data
        .drop(columns =['sex', 'prop'])
        .pivot(index = 'name', columns = 'year', values = 'n')
        .sum(axis=1) = data['decade']
        .sort_values(by = 'decade', ascending = False))
    print data[0:1]
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

My data looks like this:
[image: my data]

Its currently in longform. Can i create a middle function that converts it to wide form and builds a new column where the totals from each year (1960, 1961, ... 1969) can be added together?

Comment: Structure of your dataset? Any sample data?

Comment: All the lines of a function have to be indented.

Comment: The data is 5 columns (name, sex, year, number, and proportion).. there are over a million rows, that's why I want to convert it to a wide data frame

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1 - Name with highest n per year**

```
df.groupby(by='name', as_index=False)
      .count()
      .nlargest(1, 'number')
      .iloc[0]["name"]
```

[Sample data](https://pastebin.com/WsLbmwLM)

**Question 2 - Transform data to wideform**

[Sample data](https://pastebin.com/UAL27pW9) on which this was tested

Pivot in pandas does not do aggregations. So I split up the steps in getting totals per year and totals per decade. Finally, I join those two to get the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('set2.csv')

# add decade column
df["decade"] = df["year"] - (df["year"] % 10)

# add decade_title column to prevent join clashes
df["decade_total"] = df["decade"]
                       .apply(lambda decade_num: f"{str(decade_num)}_total")

# first pivot with n per year
per_year_df = df.pivot(index="name", columns="year", values="n")

# pivot cannot aggregate so we first aggregate and then pivot
per_decade_df = df\
    .groupby(by=["decade_total", "name"], as_index=False)\
    .agg({"n": 'sum'})\
    .pivot(index="name", columns="decade_total", values="n")

# finally we join the decade totals to the yearly counts
joined_df = per_year_df.join(per_decade_df)
```

[image: Joined result table]

Comment: But if I do this I'll have do it for each decade still. I'm trying to create one general way so that when I specifically use the 1950s data set I can just run the method to get the top name.

Comment: Ah, I misread the apart about  the datasets being split already per decade and gender. Will update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Can get rid of sorting here by using `df.groupby('name', as_index=False).nlargest(1, 'number')` which is functionally equivalent but without sorting...

Comment: @JonClements: Thanks! I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think I was unclear. I have my data all sorted by decade but I want a method that further sorts it (by creating a new column with the totals from each individual year.

Comment: @benvdh I updated my question. I'm still missing a step I think.

Comment: @D45 So basically the output you are looking for is:
columns: 1960 1961 etc.
rows: Mary Susan Linda etc.
values: n_mary_1960 n_mary_1961 etc.

So kind of like a pivot table?
And what kind of totals are you looking for? (total number of Mary's all time)?

Comment: Yes! That's what I want. And then the total would be from the decade! so an n_mary_decade